# Local maxima when multiplying two functions

Tags: real-analysis

I have two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, where:

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + a}, a>0$

and the only things I know about $g(x)$ are that:
$g(x) > 0, \forall x \in \mathbb R$
$g(x)$ is a polynomial function of some degree $n$

My question is: given a function $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$, should there be any assumptions on the smoothness of $g(x)$ if $h(x)$ is to maintain a local maximum/minimum at $x = 0$ even as a local "bump" in the product? For example, if $g(x)$ is monotonically increasing/decreasing in the neighbourhood of $x=0$ at a certain rate?

Answer (score 1):

the condition you require is that $g$ satisfies $g'(0)=0$, which is satisfied if $g(x)$ has a zero coefficient of $x$. the reason is that Leibniz rule gives:

$$
\frac{d}{dx} f(x)g(x)= f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)
$$
at $x=0$ the RHS becomes 
$$
\frac{g'(0)}a
$$
which must be zero for a maximum.

Comment: ok so this is definitely one right answer, but I don't think it covers all the possibilities. If for example $g(x)$ is a monotonically increasing/decreasing function in the neighbourhood of 0, then $f(0)g(0)$ should still give a local maximum, right?

Comment: yes, sorry i did not fully understand your question! my answer pertains only to maintaining the maximum at $x=0$. your question is much subtler

Comment: could you state your question in a more specific way?

Comment: sure, I'll try, let me know if I can clarify further - I'm still trying to formalise it properly in my head!

Comment: if $f|g$ then the maximum will be smoothed out. so you can rule out that case. otherwise one would expect some kind of trace of the bump in the product - the question is what kind?

Comment: sorry what do you mean by f|g?

Comment: $f$ divides $g$. the notation sometimes comes out a bit weak in mathjax

Comment: I see, yes that makes sense. So that question is, when do we find a "bump" in the product?